# Python script not running again

Tags: python-3.6

I always get this error whenever I tried to run my python script,

```
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\telethon\telegram_bare_client.py, line 219,
    in connect self(getconfigrequest()).dc_options
```

Please how do I fix it.

Comment: Can you please share the code that caused this error?

Comment: Could you describe how is this connected to TypeScript?